# C++, I get an infinite loop when I execute this code

Tags: c++, infinite-loop

I have been trying to find out what the problem is but i can not pinpoint it. Any help would be appreciated:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

#define infile "Input.txt"

using namespace std;


void readFromFile(int numOfPeopleAndSalary[6][2], int departmentID[50][6], int &counter, int &totalSalary)
{
    int id, depNum, salary, peopleNum;
    counter = 0;

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open(infile);

    if (myfile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Did not read the file, there is a problem" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else
    {


        while (!myfile.eof())
        {
            myfile >> id >> depNum >> salary;


            numOfPeopleAndSalary[depNum][0] = numOfPeopleAndSalary[depNum][0] + 1;
            numOfPeopleAndSalary[depNum][1] = numOfPeopleAndSalary[depNum][1] + salary;

            peopleNum = numOfPeopleAndSalary[depNum][0];

            departmentID[peopleNum][depNum] = id;

            totalSalary = totalSalary + salary;

            counter++;
        }
    }
}

int averageFunction(int counter, int totalSalary, int numOfPeopleAndSalary[6][2], int departmentID[50][6], int secondAverage[6])
{
    int average;

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        average = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        average = totalSalary / counter;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (numOfPeopleAndSalary[i][0] == 0)
        {
            secondAverage[i] = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            secondAverage[i] = numOfPeopleAndSalary[i][1] / numOfPeopleAndSalary[i][0];
        }
    }

    return average;
}

int main()
{
    int counter, average, numberOfPeeps;
    int numOfPeopleAndSalary[6][2] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int departmentID[50][6];
    int secondAverage[6];
    int totalSalary = 0;

    readFromFile(numOfPeopleAndSalary, departmentID, counter, totalSalary);

    average = averageFunction(counter, totalSalary, numOfPeopleAndSalary, departmentID, secondAverage);

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << "Department #: " << i << " Number of people: " << numOfPeopleAndSalary[i][0]
            << " Total Salary: " << numOfPeopleAndSalary[i][1] << endl;
        cout << secondAverage[i] << endl;

        numberOfPeeps = numOfPeopleAndSalary[i][0] + 1;

        cout << "----------Employee ID's---------" << endl;
        for (int j = 1; j < numberOfPeeps; i++)
        {
            cout << departmentID[j][i] << endl;
        }

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this it should just read the information from an external file (Input.txt) and make all the calculations. Inside the external file i have these test cases:

```
23 1 66
6 3 54
213 5 54
434 4 24
324 4 32
789 2 32
4 2 24
345 3 32
568 5 12
24 1 67
789 3 54
24 5 56
56 2 43
9 3 45
32 4 53
67 4 75
```

You can copy and past if you like.

Comment: Instead of `if (myfile.fail())` try `if (!myfile.is_open())` and instead of `while (!myfile.eof())` try `while(myfile >> id >> depNum >> salary)` and remove the same line from the while body.

Comment: for (int j = 1; j < numberOfPeeps; i++)
        {
            cout << departmentID[j][i] << endl;
        } i++?

Answer (score 4):

Replace `i++` by `j++` in `for (int j = 1; j < numberOfPeeps; i++)`

Comment: Thank you! Seems to be working. I will need to make my other checks. but so far so good.

Comment: how do you look at ~50 lines of code without an explanation or a diagnosis (other than infinite loop) and find the fault?

Comment: @bolov infinite loop is the key part, just go and find loops, plus loop conditions and check for the broken one. I'm guessing that's exactly what he did.

Comment: @OMGtechy exactly :)